# Mvvmcross: Text format binding with MvxLang

Tags: xamarin, translation, mvvmcross

I am building a native Xamarin app, and I am using **Mvvmcross** to do it. It is a really nice tool but I am still learning about how it works.

I found in the documentation yould could do the following thing with binding:

```
local:MvxBind="Text Format('Line: {0}', Line.Name)"
```

Here your binding the `Testclass.Name` variable with the format, so the result will be

> Line: TestName

Now I want to do the same thing but also taking in a count the **translation** for `Line:`. So normally for translation you do the following.

```
local:MvxLang="Text Line_Label"
```

**So my idea was to do something like this:**

```
local:MvxLang="Text Format('{0}{1}', Line_Label, Line.Name)"
```

**But it doesn't work like this. Does anybody have an idea if this is possible yet and how?**

Comment: I've not seen that one before, but i guess it would be a nice feature! Can you open an issue for that? On a side note, it is also possible to get a translation in a normal binding, and then you can use the format().

Comment: @Martijn00 ok I will open an issue for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Tibet binding with local:MvxBind. Let's assume, that you have:

1. BaseViewModel.cs

   ```
   public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
   {
       public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource
       {
           get
           {
               return new MvxLanguageBinder(
                   Constants.GeneralNamespace,
                   GetType().Name);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. MainViewModel.cs inheriting from BaseViewModel, with string property Name:

   ```
   public string Name => "Radek";
   ```
3. TextProviderBuilder like in Stuart's N+1 days (no. 21) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkxHtbJ_Tlk
4. JSON translation file with "MyLabel" key

   ```
   {
      "MyLabel" : "Your name:"
   }
   ```

**Answer:** Then Android layout axml file will contain binding

```
    local:MvxBind="Text Language(TextSource,'MyLabel') + ' ' + Name; Click NextCommand"
```

I don't know how to do this with local:MvxLang but the code above does the job :)